# YouTube Video ID Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, youtube, generator

How can I create Videos IDs with javascript?
I want to make a website that gives user random videos, but at the same time for me, I want to learn what is the YouTube Video ID algorithm

Comment: ask youtube :))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a random YouTube video with the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315416/how-do-i-get-a-random-youtube-video-with-the-youtube-api)

Comment: I don't wantAPI, I want to learn the algorithm of videos IDs

Comment: In the context of the video https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8 2:23 I tried all YT videos ids incrementally and found the "rarest" video id: 0000088ZZQg
Because YT videos ids are made of 11 characters there are 64^11 possibilities.
I tried 8,733,472,426 possibilities with the YT Data API v3 and found the "rarest" video id beginning with 5 zeros.
I did that because it proves that YT video ids aren't long enough because this video could be unlisted and then this would be a critical security and privacy issue.
By the way we can then badly approximate the number of YouTube videos to 8,448,755,855.

Answer (score 0):

The process is is straight forward when laid out this way:

1. Generate random unsigned 64-bit ID number
2. Check if ID already exists; if so, repeat (1)
3. Generate Base64 string of ID, by splitting into 8-bit chunks
4. Replace `/` with `-`. Replace `+` with `_`. Delete `=` if present

Here's a simple JS implementation, though it doesn't do any checks (that's usually done server side):

```js
function yt_rand_id() {
let chars2replace = {'/': '-', '+': '_', '=': ''};
let random_bytes = new Uint8Array(8).map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 256))
let base64_hash = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(0, random_bytes));
base64_hash = base64_hash.replace(/[/+=]/g, match => chars2replace[match]);
return base64_hash;
}

console.log(yt_rand_id(), yt_rand_id(), yt_rand_id(), yt_rand_id());
```

Hope this helped someone.